# Блокировка windows

Tags: java, windows

Всем привет, хочу написать Свою программку для блокировки windows от детей. Подскажите на чем лучше писать. И насколько реально написать на Java в среде Intellij Idea?
Дело в том что я уже хорошо знаком со средой и языком, программируя под андроид (хобби). Но в винде после делфи лет 10 назад ничего не писал.

И сразу же вопросы в голове, какие команды управляют виндой, как заблокировать мышку, как заставить прогу быть главней остальных, чтобы диспетчер не вызывался??

Comment: Для подобных целей, Java – не самый лучший выбор.

Comment: Вам нужно почитать о WinAPI, и об административных политиках.

Comment: Согласен с коллегой, Java не лучший вариант. Тут скорее C++ или С.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем вам не угодил LogonScreen с паролем?

Управлять Windows можно только через WinAPI. Всё остальное это "прослойки" и "обёртки" (в итоге всё равно вызывающие API), и они имеются далеко не для всего.
Можете взять C++ или Делфи/FreePascal, вроде как C# тоже подойдёт. На VB будет весело, но тоже в итоге выйдет.
А спрашивать тут "какие команды" плохая идея, это надо писать в Гугл, добавив через запятые что на WinAPI и для такого-то ЯП.

Comment: Думал написать комментарием, но мне не позволило, извините если что. Но в целом это как бы всё что вообще можно было по данной теме сказать.